# From API req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, destructuring

When I fetch this API, values will be passed to API as req.body containing {password, cpassword, hash}

In API code, I want to destructuring hash from req.body and console.log both hash and req.body

```
const { hash } = req.body
console.log(req.body)
console.log(hash)
```

The result for `console.log(req.body)` is `{"password":"g3W*&QRW3wwO","cpassword":"g3W*&QRW3wwO","hash":"6348dc387be01030c2779315"}`

And result for `console.log(hash)` is `undefined`

Why is that so? And if I would like to use the info from req.body like req.body.hash or req.body.password. How could I code that?

Comment: Can you add your complete request/response code?

Comment: Does `req.body` happen to be a string? Not sure how else this would happen

Comment: `console.log(typeof req.body);` will verify, and `const { hash } = JSON.parse(req.body);` will fix.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your body is returning a string you have to parse.  You can try checking by using typeof, in which case you could use `JSON.parse(req.body)`.  You might want to consider adding a null check as well.